# Validate Spring properties configuration in CI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, continuous-integration

When migrating to a newer Spring, there are some hints for renaming properties. I would like to have a validation, that tells me there are deprecated properties that I should fix. And ideally, also tell me I'm using properties that are unknown - when there is nowhere to bind them (no appropriate Properties class)

IDEA does this, but that is not enough, I need to be able to check this in our CI build.

[image: spring properties migration]

A maven build step would be ideal, but any idea is appreciated. Thanks